# JavaFX: custom TextArea for hex encoded content

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

I am currently trying to create a custom TextArea in JavaFX that makes it easy to input hex-encoded content. The main constraints are:

1. The text is linked to a `Property<byte[]>` that contains the binary equivalent of the string (e.g. `"ff"` is stored as `{0xff}`.
2. The only valid characters are hex digits (`0123456789abcdef`). Only for presentation reasons, upper case digits are turned to lower case (e.g. `1Bd5` is displayed as `1bd5`).
3. **The area displays the hex string in blocks of two characters.**

The third requirement is where I have found most of the problems. What I have done so far is to add a `changeListener` to the area's `textProperty`, so that every time the text on the field is changed, the format is preserved. The code looks like this:

```
textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        String correctedNewValue = validated(newValue);
        if (!correctedNewValue .equals(newValue)) 
            textProperty().setValue(correctedNewValue);
    }
});
```

Where `validated(String)` returns a `String` that fulfills the format requirements of the component. This works like a charm when a new character is inserted: the rules are enforced and the format is preserved without the user having to type the spaces manually. However, when content is deleted and I try to delete the spaces automatically, a nasty exception is produced:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at javafx.scene.control.TextArea$TextAreaContent.insert(TextArea.java:136)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:1204)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.updateContent(TextInputControl.java:556)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:548)   
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.deleteText(TextInputControl.java:496)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.deletePreviousChar(TextInputControl.java:899)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin.deleteChar(TextAreaSkin.java:1351)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextAreaBehavior.deleteChar(TextAreaBehavior.java:274)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.deletePreviousChar(TextInputControlBehavior.java:311)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:143)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextAreaBehavior.callAction(TextAreaBehavior.java:259)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What I have seen so far is that a property should not be changed within the listener that detects changes on the same property, and some sources suggest to use `Platform.runLater`. However, this is very erratic (the caret changes position -usually to the beginning of the field-, and sometimes the focus gets lost).

My question is: what is the best way to go about this hex field? How can I update the textProperty correctly? (I would be willing to use an existing component as well, but since I did not find it, I figured I could try to build it myself).

Comment: I could not read everything, but have you tried to use the method `equalsIgnoreCase()` in your condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a TextFormatter to remove a tailing whitespace. Basically you check if the change is a delete and if the resulting text ends with a whitespace, you adjust the start of the deletion to remove this whitespace, too.

```
         UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = new UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>() {

            @Override
            public TextFormatter.Change apply(TextFormatter.Change c) {

                if (c.isDeleted()) {
                    if (c.getControlNewText()
                         .endsWith(" ")) {
                        c.setRange(c.getRangeStart() - 1, c.getRangeEnd());
                    }
                }
                if (c.isAdded()) {
                }
                if (c.isReplaced()) {
                }
                return c;
            }
        };

        yourTextField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(filter));
```